# Не работает поиск объекта в массиве

Tags: c#

У меня есть массив Clothes[]. Если объект не повторяется, то он просто добавляется в массив. Если объект повторяется, который уже имеется в массиве, то он увеличивается на то, что нужно. Но в строке  `var duplicate = clothes.FirstOrDefault(c => c == find);` постоянно null. Соответственно, что условие не выполняется и повторяющейся объект добавляется в массив, хотя не должен, по идеи. Как это сделать правильно, чтобы работало?

```
Clothes[] clothes = new Clothes[clothesVendor.Length];
     for (int i = 0; i < clothesVendor.Length; i++)
                { 
                    var find = await _context.Clothes.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.VendorCode == clothesVendor[i]);
                    var duplicate = clothes.FirstOrDefault(c => c == find);
                    
                    if (find != null )
                    {
    
                        if (duplicate != null)
                        {
                             duplicate.Price += duplicate.Price;
                             duplicate.Amount += 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            clothes[i] = find;
                        }
                           
                    }
    
                 
                }
```

Comment: equals поди не перегрузили

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault(c => c.VendorCode == find.VendorCode);`

Comment: Если использовать `.FirstOrDefault(c => c.VendorCode == find.VendorCode);`, то будет исключение: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Проверку `find` на `null` нужно делать сразу же. И лишь потом искать duplicate.

Comment: @witchblvd это настолько сложно? Точно помощь нужна?